# How to set box shadow via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I know you can do the following:

```
element.style.box-shadow ="something";
```

How would I cover -moz and -webkit extensions?

If I did `element.style.-webkit-box-shadow="something"` and `element.style.-moz-box-shadow="something"`, would I be covered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option is called `webkitBoxShadow`, `mozBoxShadow`, etc. - to convert a CSS option name to a `.style.` property remove the leading dash and then convert it from `lowercase-with-dashes` to `lowerCamelCase.`

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to set a class that declares those shadow properties for the various browsers and append that class to the `className` of the target element.

something like:

```
.shadowed{
    /*all shadow declarations for various browsers*/ 
    -o-
    -webkit-
    -moz-
    -ms-
    box-shadow
}

element.className += ' shadowed';
```

Comment: you may want to put a space before the new class: `' shadowed';`

Answer (score 0):

```
element.style['-webkit-box-shadow'] = "something";
```

Or in Mozilla:

```
element.style['-moz-box-shadow'] = "something";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try out this for text shadow .
and for box shadow just replace text with box.

```
<html>
 <body>

  <p id="demo">Text shadow.</p>

   <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Add shadow to text</button>

   <script>
   function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("demo").style.textShadow="2px 2px 4px green";
 }
 </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).